# How to show the following function is injective?

Tags: functions

$f : \mathbb{Z}_{12} \to \mathbb{Z_4} \times \mathbb{Z_6}$ defined by $x \mapsto (x \mod 4, x \mod 6)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. Then, we know $(x \mod 4, x \mod 6) = (y \mod 4, y \mod 6)$, so $x \equiv y \pmod{4}$ and $x \equiv y \pmod{6}$. Since the lowest common multiple of $4$ and $6$ is $12$, we have $x \equiv y \pmod{12}$. Hence, as $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$, we must have $x = y$, as they have the same residue modulo $12$.

Therefore, $f$ is injective.